# How to add single quote at the end of ONLY the last line of a file

Tags: awk, sed, files, string

I want a non-perl solution where I should be able to append a single quote `'` at the last visible (non-escape characters) line of a file and save it back to the file.

cat example.txt

```
var1: 'funn'
var2: 'weee'
var3: 'youuuu
```

Expected output

cat example.txt

```
var1: 'funn'
var2: 'weee'
var3: 'youuuu'
```

I know how to print the last line using `awk` and how to append a character at the end of each line but cannot get the file updated with appending the single quote only to the last line and updating the file.

Comment: @they it does not answer as i wish to append single quote and not replace string

Comment: How is what you want to do different? Replacing the end of line with a single quote does sound like the same thing as replacing some string with another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sed` expression `$s/$/'/` adds a single quote to the end of the last line of input.   The first `$` is the "address" of the last line.  When the last line is found, this triggers the given substitution, `s`, command.  That command replaces the end of the line, matched by `$` in the regular expression, with a single quote.

Would you want to perform the substitution only if the line does not already have a single quote at the end of it, then use `$s/[^']$/&'/`.  This replaces the last character on the last line with itself, followed by a single quote, but only if that last character is not a single quote. Of course, this does require that there is at least one character on the line already.

In the shell, you can use these `sed` expressions in double-quotes, but you need to escape the two dollar signs from the shell:

```bsh
sed "\$s/\$/'/" file
```

```bsh
sed "\$s/[^']\$/&'/" file
```

If your `sed` supports it, you may use it with `-i` to perform an in-place edit on the file.

To apply this on only the last non-blank line in the file (and also delete the trailing blank-only lines), first, delete the blank lines at the end of the file.  One way to do this is with the following pipeline:

```bsh
tac file | sed '1,/[[:graph:]]/ { /[[:graph:]]/!d; }' | tac
```

This reverses the lines of the file with GNU `tac`, removes all lines up to the first non-blank line ("non-blank" meaning it has some graph character on it; you could use `[^[:space:]]` in place of `[[:graph:]]`), and then reverses the lines again.

Modifying the last line of this pipeline's output:

```bsh
tac file | sed '1,/[[:graph:]]/ { /[[:graph:]]/!d; }' | tac |
sed "\$s/\$/'/" >file.new
```

Or, combining the two `sed` invocations:

```bsh
tac file | sed "1,/[[:graph:]]/ { /[[:graph:]]/\!d; s/\$/'/; }" | tac >file.new
```

(Note the escaping of `!` without which some shell may try to do a history expansion.)

... then just replace `file` with `file.new` using `mv`.