# How to make sure that the last character of each line of a file ends with single quote character

Tags: awk, sed, files, string

I have a file which has several lines.

I wish to update the file while making sure that the last visible character of each line of the file is a single quote `'`. In case not, then we should add the single quote at the end of each line.

If the single quote is the last character in a line then leave it as is.

cat test.txt

```
fahsjhjkhkjhjhajkhjf
afasfsfsfffsfasf'
aaffa' sfff
wfafsfsaffs'
fsafsfs'afffafsasf
```

Expected output:

```
fahsjhjkhkjhjhajkhjf'
afasfsfsfffsfasf'
aaffa' sfff'
wfafsfsaffs'
fsafsfs'afffafsasf'
```

Comment: You were just [shown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697014/65304) how to do this on the *last* line of a file: `sed "\$s/[^']\$/&'/" file`. To do it on *any* line, just remove the `\$` address condition.

Comment: @steeldriver i tried `tac test.txt | sed '1,/[[:graph:]]/ { /[[:graph:]]/!d; }' | tac | sed "\$s/[^']/&'/"` and it does not work on the sample i provided.

Comment: i also tried `tac test.txt  | sed '1,/[[:graph:]]/ { /[[:graph:]]/!d; }' | tac | sed "\$s//'/"` but i get error `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Comment: Why would you want to use `tac`? Don't treat programming as a "cargo cult" but instead take some time to try and understand the solutions you're given. It makes things so much easier...

Comment: If you can have empty input lines that you want changes to a single `'` then include that case in your example as some potential solutions would fail given that input. What should the output be if an input line ends with 2 `'`s, e.g. would input of `foo''` output `foo''` or `foo'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` expression `s/[^']$/&'/` inserts a single quote at the end of any line that ends with a character that is not a single quote.

In the shell:

```bsh
sed "s/[^']$/&'/" file
```

Since the expression contains a single quote, I'm choosing to write the expression in double quotes instead.  To make an in-place edit, use `sed` with its `-i` option if it implements this nonstandard option at all.

To also insert a single quote on empty lines, you could use an extra expression targeting empty lines specifically, or you could *always* insert a single quote at the end of the line and then replace any double single quotes that this results in.

I.e., either

```bsh
sed -e "s/[^']$/&'/" -e "/^$/s//'/" file
```

or

```bsh
sed -e "s/$/'/" -e "s/''$/'/" file
```

Answer (score 2):

If matching the single quote whether it is there or not, and if present, replacing it is acceptable, then you can try this `sed`.

```
$ sed "s/\([^']*\)'\?$/\1'/" input_file
'fahsjhjkhkjhjhajkhjf'
afasfsfsfffsfasf'
aaffa' sfff'
wfafsfsaffs'
fsafsfs'afffafsasf'
```

This uses back referencing to capture every character up to the end of the line. If a single quote is found at the end of the line, then it is excluded/removed by placing the single quote outside of the capturing parenthesis.

Everything captured within the parenthesis is then returned with `\1` with the single quote hardcoded to the end of each line.

Comment: Interesting approach. You should say more about how/why this works, and why you chose it over they’s shorter (and, arguably, more obvious) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697021/80216#697027). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

something like can do the work:

```
awk -v a=\' '{print $0 a}'  input.file
```

If you want to avoid double quotes on the end you can try something like:

```
 awk -v a=\' '{print $0 a}'  input.file|sed "s/''$/'/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `sed` as it is supposed to.

To add a `'` at the end of *all*  lines you do

```
sed "s/$/'/" file
```

To do an operation on some lines only, you use an *address*. The address of lines ending with `'` is `/'$/`. You invert the address seletion by a `!`, so you get

```
sed "/'$/!s/$/'/" file
```

Short, functional, portable and also covering the empty-line-case.

(Beware not to have stupid history expansion active: `set +H`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want empty input lines to become `'` in the output and input like `foo''` to be output as `foo'`:

```
$ sed "s/'*$/'/" file
fahsjhjkhkjhjhajkhjf'
afasfsfsfffsfasf'
aaffa' sfff'
wfafsfsaffs'
fsafsfs'afffafsasf'
```